# Can you strip carriage returns from CSS files?

Tags: css

Can you strip carriage returns from CSS files safely?

I have an PHP example in in this case, but the question is for any programming language.

Given the following sequence of tasks in minifying CSS.

```
START prepare CSS
# removeComments( $this->rawCSS );
# trimLines( $css );
# stripSpaces( $css );
$css = str_replace( array( "\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t" ) , '' , $css );
# removeDoubleSpaces( $css );
# removePunctuationSpaces( $css );
# enforceInternetExplorerLineLengthLimit( $css );
# migrateImportsToTop( $css );
DONE prepare CSS
```

Will the removal of characters HT (9), LF (10), FF (12), CR (13) ever leave the CSS in an invalid condition?

Comment: My own recommendation to the author is $css = str_replace( array( "\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t" ) , ' ' , $css ); so that only the whitespace character is changed so any css grammer is unchanged. However I am getting a load of abuse along the lines of nobody does that (or will do that). What I am hoping for is somone to come up with something irrefutable.

Comment: Conclusion: carriage returns cannot be removed from css safely as you cannot guantee that css components are not separated by other whitespace thereby acting as a concatemator. - John

Comment: Replacing /[\s\n\r]{1,}/g with a single white space character will still leave the CSS in a valid state. I believe this is the safest approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: you can surely change the meaning of some property:

```
.someClass::after{    
    content: 'Some content here';
}
```

if the words are separated by TAB HT (9) you will end up with

```
content: 'Somecontenthere';
```

It can also broke some rule i think

```
.someClass
A{
color:white
}
```

it's perfectly valid css but it will end up as

```
.someClassA{color:white}
```

which is a different rule.

Comment: .someClass::after{content: 'Some content here';}// whatss the issue ?

Comment: That code is valid even after removing all whitespace.

Comment: _Can you strip carriage returns from CSS files safely?_ that would be valid, but not safe. it will change the meaning of the code. Unless you merely look at the syntax rules, but i don't think this is what the user is asking.

Comment: I removed my downvote and upvoted your edit. I didn't remember you could separate sequencial selectors with returns.

Answer (score 2):

Lists of values for properties are often separated by white space, which can be a new line. Given this code:

```css
div { border: solid
red
1px;
  }
```

```html
<div>content</div>
```

… stripping new lines would result in:

```
border: solidred1px;
```

… which would be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, removing line breaks/tabs could make CSS invalid.

An example:

```
@import
url("imported.css");
```

would become invalid:

```
@importurl("imported.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because of some comments.

```
// This is my precious class
.preciousClass {
  color: yellow;
}
```

When you remove all whitespace, though, this happens. It's not syntactically invalid, but it is not working any longer.

```
// This is my precious class.preciousClass {  color: yellow;}
```

But otherwise, your CSS won't be invalid just by removing non-space whitespace.

Comment: Line comments `//` are not valid in CSS.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'll just leave this here to remind me of my mistake.

Comment: # removeComments( $this->rawCSS ); removes /***/ anyway :)